# how to summarize list of objects by property

Tags: c#, list

I have list of Customer object, my goal is to summarize how much money this customer paid.

```
class Customer
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Paid {get; set;}
}
```

for example, if the list contain the following:

`[{"Bob",90},{"Tom",120},{"Bob",120,{"Alex",67},{"Tom",40}}]`

Then the expected result Should be

```
[{"Bob",210},{"Tom",160},{"Alex",67}}]
```

Here is my list

```
List<Customer> customers = ...
```

How it can achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Customer> customers = ...

var summarized = customers
    .GroupBy( c => c.Name )
    .Select( grp => new
    {
        Name  = grp.Key,
        Total = grp.Sum( c => c.Paid )
    } )
    .OrderByDescending( s => s.Total )
    .ToList();
```